# Integrating an array in scipy with bounds.

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to integrate over an array of data, but with bounds. Therfore I planned to use simps (scipy.integrate.simps). Because simps itself does not support bounds I decided to feed it only the selection of my data I want to integrate over. Yet this leads to strange results which are twice as big as the expected outcome.

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing, or missunderstanding?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scipy import integrate
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# my data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 30)
y = x**2

# but I only want to integrate from 3 to 5
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
x_selection = np.linspace(3, 5, 10)
y_selection = f(x_selection)

# quad returns the expected result
print 'quad', integrate.quad(f, 3, 5), '<- the expected value (includig error estimation)'
# but simps returns an uexpected result, when using the selected data
print 'simps', integrate.simps(x_selection, y_selection), '<- twice as big'
print 'trapz', integrate.trapz(x_selection, y_selection), '<- also twice as big'

plt.plot(x, y, marker='.')
plt.fill_between(x, y, 0, alpha=0.5)

plt.plot(x_selection, y_selection, marker='.')
plt.fill_between(x_selection, y_selection, 0, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Windows7, python2.7, scipy1.0.0

Comment: You have flipped the calling arguments; `simps` and `trapz` expect first the `y` dimension, and second the `x` dimension, as per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#integrating-functions-given-fixed-samples). Once you have corrected this, similar results should obtain. Note that your example function admits a trivial analytic antiderivative, which would be much cheaper to evaluate.

Comment: @N.Wouda Thank you so much. For an hour I have read the documentation, Started to question my undestanding of integration and wasted my first question on stackoverflow on a simple argument swap mistake. Thank you very much for your time. (I know that there is an analytical solution for this example, I probably should have used a more random set of data) I have just missed that x and y are 'sawped'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arguments for simps() and trapz() are in the wrong order.

> You have flipped the calling arguments; simps and trapz expect first the y dimension, and second the x dimension, as per the docs. Once you have corrected this, similar results should obtain. Note that your example function admits a trivial analytic antiderivative, which would be much cheaper to evaluate.

– N. Wouda